# Organ pipe, waves, longitudinal waves, traverse waves

Tags: classical-mechanics

We all know that organ pipe work because of longitudinal stationary sound waves then why in diagrams showing the analysis of the physics behind the organ pipe transverse waves are drawn inside the pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in what you've said. The reason they are drawn as transverse waves is because they are easier to draw and visualize than if you were to try and draw them as longitudinah waves. Furthermore a standing wave is not a wave in itself but rather an interference of two waves traveling in opposite directions. The transverse wave illustration is a convenient way to show it.